# Primary key not auto generating in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

So my requirement is to generate ids for route and they must be 3 digits. I have applied the generated value annotation and also created the generator classes as below but still getting an error that id cannot be null when trying to save the entity.

RouteEntity.java

```
     @Entity
        @Table(name="route")


         public class RouteEntity {
                @Id              
 @GenericGenerator(name="train_id",
strategy="com.infyrail.app.generator.RouteIdGenerator")
            @GeneratedValue(generator = "train_id")
                @Min(value = 100)
                @Max(value = 999)
            Integer id;

            String source;
            String destination;
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "route",
                    cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)

            private List<TrainEntity> trainList;
            public Integer getId() {
                return id;
            }
            public void setId(Integer id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
            public String getSource() {
                return source;
            }
            public void setSource(String source) {
                this.source = source;
            }
            public String getDestination() {
                return destination;
            }
            public void setDestination(String destination) {
                this.destination = destination;
            }
            public List<TrainEntity> getTrainList() {
                return trainList;
            }
            public void setTrainList(List<TrainEntity> trainList) {
                this.trainList = trainList;
            }

        }
```

RouteIdGenerator.java

```
package com.infyrail.app.generator;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;

public class RouteIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    private static Integer counter = 101;

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) {
        Integer id = counter++;

        return  id;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Samrat Das, I didn't see any issue with your code. it should work perfectly as you wrote. If it's not working for you, then it could a different issue. to isolate the issue, you may remove additional attributes from Entity class and mapping (ex: trainEntity) and try.

Comment: Yeah I think it was a db issue had to create a new schema..working fine now